# JQuery not opening dialog on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to make a simple form that checks if pass1 and pass2 fields are equal on submit button press: if they are, data will be submitted; else, a dialog is shown.

However, the button does not show a dialog at all, and I get no error from console. Here is the script:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit_button").click(function() {
    if ($("#pass1").val() == $("#pass2").val() && $("#pass1").val().length != 0) {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
            return false;
        }
    }

    $('#dialog').dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        height: 200
    });
}
```

Here is my form:

```
<form id="signup_form" method="post" class="form"> 
    <p class="pass1"> 
        <input type="password" name="pass1" id="pass1" /> 
        <label for="pass1">Password</label> 
    </p> 

    <p class="pass2"> 
        <input type="password" name="pass2" id="pass2" /> 
        <label for="pass2">Confirm Password</label> 
    </p> 

    <p class="submit"> 
        <input id="submit_button" type="button" value="Submit" /> 
    </p> 
</form>

<div id="dialog">
    Passwords must be equal!
</div>
```

I got the compare function from another question on stackoverflow and the button click function from another page I made, so I must be missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you add the jquery UI library? ref =>  https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: I did include JQuery but not the UI library! However, I do get an error now.

Comment: Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/u51d96qj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with calling dialog with open option. **$("#dialog").dialog("open" );**
[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c6w2yLyd/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit_button").click(function() {

    if ($("#pass1").val() == $("#pass2").val() && $("#pass1").val().length != 0) {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open" );
            return false;
        }
    });

    $('#dialog').dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        height: 200
    });
});
```

Comment: There might be syntax error in your code. check the code in answer or in fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <form id="signup_form" method="post" class="form"> 
        <p class="pass1"> 
            <input type="password" name="pass1" id="pass1" /> 
            <label for="pass1">Password</label> 
        </p> 

        <p class="pass2"> 
            <input type="password" name="pass2" id="pass2" /> 
            <label for="pass2">Confirm Password</label> 
        </p> 

        <p class="submit"> 
            <input id="submit_button" type="button" value="Submit" /> 
        </p> 
    </form>

    <div id="dialog" style="display:none">
        Passwords must be equal!
    </div>


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit_button").click(function() {
            if ($("#pass1").val() != $("#pass2").val() && $("#pass1").val().length != 0) {
                $( "#dialog" ).dialog("open");
                return false;
            }
        });
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            modal: false,
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 600,
            height: 200
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o427h8L8/

Answer (score 1):

In script code, according to your condition dialog box is shown when password & confirm password are equal. So keep a not condition for if...

```
if ($("#pass1").val() != $("#pass2").val() && $("#pass1").val().length == 0) {
       $( "#dialog" ).dialog("open");
       return false;
    }
```

And also make button as "submit" so when password & confirm password are equal it is submitted to server.

```
<form id="signup_form" method="post" class="form" action="Your FileName"> 
<p class="pass1"> 
    <input type="password" name="pass1" id="pass1" /> 
    <label for="pass1">Password</label> 
</p> 

<p class="pass2"> 
    <input type="password" name="pass2" id="pass2" /> 
    <label for="pass2">Confirm Password</label> 
</p> 

<p class="submit"> 
    <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</p>
```